# Jenkins Pipeline when condition

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Pipeline as source in a `Jenkinsfile`

I am not using a multibranch pipeline so I can't use the standard when condition for branch selection. The host for my git repository is gitlab and I am using the gitlab plugin though so I can see that this environment variable is set:

`Name: gitlabSourceBranch -> Value continuous_integration`

However, when I try and use this environment variable in a stage when condition, I just get:

`Stage "build_sd_card" skipped due to when conditional`

The when condition I am using is:

```
        when {
          environment name: 'gitlabSourceBranch ', value: 'continuous_integration'
        }
```

I used the jenkins syntax declarative directive generator to generate it.

I printed out the environment with this function (called within the preceeding stage):

```
@NonCPS
def printParams() {
  env.getEnvironment().each { name, value -> println "Name: $name -> Value $value" }
}
```

Why isn't this `when` condition working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare value with input value.

As you know environment values are set (or can be set) and are accessible under the env. prefix. You should use something like:

```
  when {
    equals expected: 'continuous_integration', actual: env.gitlabSourceBranch
  }
```

or

```
when {
     expression {
         env.gitlabSourceBranch == 'continuous_integration'
     } 
}
```

Though I prefer the first